# XLST: Copy ID from one childnode to another childnode

Tags: xslt, copy, element

I've been looking for this for a while now and tried lots of options, which al partially do what i want. I'm not familiar enough with XSLT to combine these into the thing i want. Help is appreciated.

My xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
    <id>1</id>
    <child>
        <a>sample</a>
    </child>
</parent>

<parent>
    <id>2</id>
    <child>
        <a>sample</a>
    </child>
</parent>
```

the output has to be as follows:

```
<parent>
    <id>1</id>
    <child>
        <id>1</d>
        <a>sample</a>
    </child>
</parent>

<parent>
    <id>2</id>
    <child>
        <id>2</id>
        <a>sample</a>
    </child>
</parent>
```

I found an xsl code that does what i want but it copys the attribute, whilst i need to copy the number within the id (no its not an option to make id's an attribute). I also wonder if its possible for the xls to know which parent/id has to attach to which child, since they are all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your input XML misses a root element, therefore I used this input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <parent>
        <id>1</id>
        <child>
            <a>sample</a>
        </child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <id>2</id>
        <child>
            <a>sample</a>
        </child>
    </parent>
</data>
```

If I apply this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity to copy all elements -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Match on element child and copy this element, but on top add a new element
          <id> and fill this with the ancestor element called parent and it's child id -->
    <xsl:template match="child">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" /> <!-- Copy attributes first because we will add a node after this -->
            <id><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::parent/id" /></id>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <parent>
        <id>1</id>
        <child>
            <id>1</id>
            <a>sample</a>
        </child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <id>2</id>
        <child>
            <id>2</id>
            <a>sample</a>
        </child>
    </parent>
</data>
```

Comment: If child had any attribute (it's not the case of current input) then it would fail because it would apply templates for attributes after `<id>` output.

Comment: Indeed it will. I adjusted my answer. Thanks for the correction

Comment: Yeah i got a root error, added the root element and it worked perfect with the ../id.  Wish i had seen this post before I found about that though hehe. Also thanks for the explanation on what every line does. Great!